# When a static method is called from a reference variable of type A, Java will find yourself where that method?

Tags: java, oop

When a static method is called from a reference variable of type A, Java will find yourself where that method?

a) Class which objects are shown to belong

b) Class A

c) Starting from the class that the object is shown to belong, if not see, then look at the superclass.

d) sublayer of A

```
public class A {      
    public static void get(){
        System.out.println();
    }
   }

public class B extends A {
       public static void get(){
        System.out.println("this is Get() method ");
    }
   }

public static void main(String args[]){
       A a=new A();
       A b=new B();
         a.get();
         b.get(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the program will print two empty lines because both calls are directed to the static method of class A.

This is because static calls are evaluated not at runtime but a compile time and you can't use override functionality with them.

So in both cases the visible class is "A" thus the static method get() of A will be invoked.